# Should we synomyze [google-play] and [google-play-store] or burninate [google-play]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have

- [google-play](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play)  4 questions, 5 watchers
- [google-play-store](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store) 28 questions, 1 watcher

They look to be about the same. Since [google-play](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play) has more watchers than [google-play-store](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store) what will be the best way to proceed?

Make one a synonym of the other? and in such case which one should be made the main tag?

Or just retag the [google-play](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play) questions to "burninate" this tag?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we want to synonymize. Google Play also encompasses Google Play Music, Google Play Movies, etc.

Probably better to retag those that are specifically about the store.

Comment: I just found [What is Google Play?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46001/88163) that includes an answer by you from 2013. As I understood it, it says that Google Play is Google Play Store. Is that right?